# Why does removing a value from the array remove the typescript error?

Tags: typescript

This is part of a big project where I'm basically creating virtual HTML elements for a type of editor I'm making. I spent a long time trying to narrow it down and I arrived at the following snippet. Changing many random things about this snippet removes the error. Even removing one of the `hChildren` removes the error. Here is the [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgGzgWzmKEYF4YG0BEAFgIz4A0MRATOZYQMy1EAsTARgK5RTj4C6MAIaZQkKAG4AUJNHQYhAMKEAlggAmAJzTY8kmJQDqiUKhg8YAeQ4aYRthGVQ4AQnJ7KACUQIQFAyA11VzJ3fAARZQhQADc4GwBZALg3fXwAUQAPAAcfLUtrGABlOOjlYDgIFMoAcThYQqhBDSc1GAAVEDVBAE8q-ABBNhAuGABVSpDUhXBG4FhxtwFhGFkJaVWYTm5wJVVNbRwCACENEAB3CGSlkXBoKUkAMw4wOeVwGABzOoAlQTA1EDIABqggQHDgAB42vAMk5-pgtIIAWAEN0YNANMowB9cHwAHwACiaGgAXO0AJRktq4MAcZBsOICADe7g2Gj+AOQAEl-nAMjp4oIoIQAHQPHwBAmC4Ui9n-QEE8kwABUQg0GhFSGxwvJUn0Wig1jAao0uDlnJ5aj5fCkAF91rdYMLIv4NABrCD9CCZLJwOZwVo4AmND4AOUEqCpgjDEbgSqweJgLP0ygeMGD0fDpiwObopBgAB8C2ZM7HsLnqPhC8WQ1m4OWcERGErk-oYAajUn3G2SzHUJMeysVOotGAyV8oL95cDQeCCYph-swOSB-pbXqYPb3B2NMbW-pa7GB+vJCeZI6zCoIGEQBV0K63V6fX6WjoM324FGP-HE63U+nu17OsGzzKsi0Aw9swrQgaGrCDSygxsGDAgt4I-ECWHwdwW0Anc90Ag8ELgVc22ARdR3HH4OUBEEwTgeddhHNAV0Ak812kfU6k7fcgKPdwTzPKBul9doiLfITfRANNEBQNAMHJGk6QZDQbWkCT6yOYQ4DSJBUHQKEYThNRMDaIiKAUQy0GM9EoExbFExwVtIM-doNzIvZRwAfjJBQ7XudSYCBZRmg4UEdNk9BsHcYtNMucK9KgCEiFIChg2EuApPkRilwU2l6UZPFopgWLtN0uSkpg2g0sktMFw85jFPylTCv0GKtPi8qmyq9TMrqpjl0a5T8SKkqOv0zDUp62rstHXKlIKkb2rK8ath4MBuvSzLVp2ciGryoa8XuGSEogMUAjSQQyIJd86x-Lt9A2ThVCgIKQrC5aoGIMlXsNd6ItgHBnQgB9PW9bIXwDG7Y11VlbhAJBNRAD4CSehAXuC36EDGz6YYei9UfRt6sY+qhvox0Lif+nQgZvO8oAfJ9wf9NQodQXGVjhhGfGRgmfop7GqBh20YaAA). Help would be appreciated.

```
const elements = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "button"] as const;

const hChildren = [
  "Welcome to Our Website!",
  "Hello, World!",
  "Discover More",
  "Explore Our Services",
  "Get Started Today",
  "About Us",
  "Contact Us",
] as const;

const buttonChildren = ["Browse"] as const;

function getRandomValue<T extends readonly string[]>(arr: T): T[number] {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return arr[randomIndex];
}

const thisWorksAsExpected = (tagName: TagName) => {
  if (tagName === "h1" || tagName === "h2" || tagName === "h3") {
    return {
      tagName,
      children: getRandomValue(hChildren),
    };
  }

  return {
    tagName,
  };
};

const thisDoesntWorkAsExpected = (tagName: TagName) => {
  if (
    tagName === "h1" ||
    tagName === "h2" ||
    tagName === "h3" ||
    tagName === "h4"
  ) {
    return {
      tagName,
      children: getRandomValue(hChildren),
    };
  }

  return {
    tagName,
  };
};

type TagName = (typeof elements)[number];

type BaseElement<T extends TagName, C extends string> = {
  tagName: T;
  children?: C;
};

type VirtualElement =
  | BaseElement<"h1", (typeof hChildren)[number]>
  | BaseElement<"h2", (typeof hChildren)[number]>
  | BaseElement<"h3", (typeof hChildren)[number]>
  | BaseElement<"h4", (typeof hChildren)[number]>
  | BaseElement<"button", (typeof buttonChildren)[number]>;

elements.forEach((tagName) => {
  const builtVirtualElement1: VirtualElement = thisWorksAsExpected(tagName);
  console.log(builtVirtualElement1);
  const builtVirtualElement2: VirtualElement = thisDoesntWorkAsExpected(tagName);
  console.log(builtVirtualElement2);
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't have worked at all before TS3.5 introduced [smarter union type checking](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) as impl in [ms/TS#30779](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30779). Unions of objects and objects of unions aren't generally comparable without lots of processing time, so TS bails out if the product of union members exceeds 25. So that's what's happening; you add too many union members for it to spend time on and it fails. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Comment: Yes I think that addresses it. Thanks @jcalz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) whose properties are of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is not generally considered equivalent to a union of object types, even if the latter union is the requisite [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).  That is, if you have `{x: A | B, y: C | D}`, that isn't necessarily seen as equivalent to `{x: A, y: C} | {x: A, y: D} | {x: B, y: C} | {x: B, y: D}`, even though any value of one type would also be a value of the other type.  The main reason is because it is *unscalably expensive* to analyze such types for even modestly sized unions.

But enough people ran into this problem and reported it (e.g., [ms/TS#12052](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052), [ms/TS#30170](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30170), etc) that eventually the TS team compromised and implemented so-called [smarter union type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) via [microsoft/TypeScript#30779](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30779). The compromise is that if that Cartesian product is small enough, it will do the checking for you and succeed or fail depending on the expansion. If it's too big, then it gives up and fails to type check no matter what.  But "too big" is rather small:

> If the number of combinations is above a fixed limit (currently **25**), we consider the comparison too complex and determine that 'source' is not related to the 'target'.

As soon as the number of possible combinations is 26 or more, it will break in exactly they way you're seeing.  *Yes*, this is confusing.  Which is why TypeScript doesn't usually do things like this.  See [this Twitter thread by the TS dev team lead](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1544414378383925250), and specifically [this entry](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1544414383878463489) and the one after:

> It's really tempting to say "Oh if the number of inputs is *small*, then do brute force". And indeed TS will do this in a small number of cases. Doing this is nice, but introduces discontinuities in behavior where e.g. an union of 15 values behaves differently from one with 16. Programmers especially hate that kind of thing because it destroys predictability.

Which leads to confused developers and Stack Overflow questions like these.  Oh well!

Comment: Great answer, very insightful!

Comment: I'd almost prefer typescript not tease me with this functionality - if it doesn't work for >= 25, it shouldn't work for less than that either, especially without a descriptive error message.